# Changed Permissions, Now Cannot see contents of Drive

Tags: permissions

I was having problems reading all files on an extra hard drive so I attempted to "fix" this with these commands as root:

```
chown dave:dave /media/250GB
chmod 644 * /media/250GB
```

I'm now unable to see the drive and mount it in my Nautilus shortcuts and I need to go into **Nautilus** → **File System** → **media** → **250GB** to see my files. I had two folders in the drive both with backed up data, but both folder now show as files which Nautilus doesn't know what to do with them (it doesn't treat them as folders).

`ls -l` reports:

```
...:/media/250GB$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 2013-01-23 19:24 2013-HOME-BACKUP
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 2013-01-23 19:22 2013-WORK-BACKUP
```

Comment: Since I had some files transferred from the 250GB drive to my Desktop I decided to run those two commands on my Desktop folder and subdirectories. I get a "ERROR : Permission Denied" note now when trying to move or open files that are on my Desktop!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1574126/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I fixed my 250GB drive by running this command...

```
sudo chmod 775 /media/250GB -R
```

...and I fixed my Desktop permission problems by running this...

```
sudo chmod 775 /home/Desktop -R
```

Comment: `755` is OK for directories, but it will make all files executable! `664` is the default permission for files.

Comment: for some reason though, unknown to me, 644 wasnt working and permissions were not being changed. After reboot everything still works.

Comment: 644 is **not** OK for directories. You applied 644 to a directory, that caused your problem. However now you have applied 775 mode to files too, not just directories. The `-R` option means "recursively descend all files and directories". So yes, you have fixed the problem with your directory, but you have introduced a problem with your files.

Comment: Ahhh. I see what you mean. If I click a TXT file it tries to run it in terminal. Do you know how do I fix this new issue?

Comment: `find ~ ! -type d -exec chmod 664 {} \;` should do the trick.